# MVC 4 - Ajax.ActionLink can't find controller method. What am I doing wrong

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, hyperlink

This is probably quite a basic question but for some reason my link can't find the controller and method.

I have this Ajax.ActionLink in a partialview called _PartialTeams.cshtml

```
@model Website.Models.modelTeamSelect

    <div id="divCreatedTeams" style="float: left; padding: 10px;">
        <h3>Your created teams:</h3>
        <input type="submit" value="Asc" name="btnSubmit" />
        <input type="submit" value="Desc" name="btnSubmit" />
        <br />
        @if (Model.teams.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < Model.teams.Count; i++)
            {
            @Html.EditorFor(m => m.teams[i].TeamName)
            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.teams[i].TeamID)
            @Ajax.ActionLink("Update team", "_PartialTeams", "Home", new {model = this.Model, id =  Model.teams[i].TeamID}, null);
            <input type="button" value="Remove team" name="btnSubmit" />
            <br />
            }
        }
    </div>
```

It is a partial view being referenced in this view

```
@model Website.Models.modelTeamSelect

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Football App";
}
@section featured {

}

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("_PartialTeams",
    new
    {
        model = this.Model
    },
    new AjaxOptions
    {
        HttpMethod = "POST",
        UpdateTargetId = "divCreatedTeams",
        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace
    }))
{

    <div id="divTeams" style="float: left; padding: 10px;">
        <h3>Create a new team:</h3>

        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.team.TeamName)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.team.TeamName)
        <input type="submit" value="Add Team" name="btnSubmit" />
    </div>

    Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Partials/_PartialTeams.cshtml");
}
```

**Website.Models.ModelTeamSelect**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Website.Models
{
    public class modelTeamSelect
    {
        public modelTeamSelect()
        {
            teams = new List<modelTeam>();
            team = new modelTeam();
        }

        public List<modelTeam> teams { get; set; }
        public modelTeam team { get; set; }
    }
}

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Website.Models
{
    public class modelTeam
    {
        public Guid TeamID { get; set; }
        public string TeamName { get; set; }
        public Guid? LeagueID { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Website.Models;
using Website.Repository;

namespace Website.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private FootballRepository FootballRepository;

        public ActionResult TeamManagement()
        {
            modelTeamSelect modelTeamSelect;
            FootballRepository = new FootballRepository();
            modelTeamSelect = FootballRepository.GetTeams();
            return View(modelTeamSelect);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult TeamManagement(string btnSubmit, modelTeamSelect modelTeamSelect)
        {
            switch (btnSubmit)
            {
                case "Add Team":
                    // For now - add to collection but not use DAL
                    modelTeamSelect.teams.Add(modelTeamSelect.team);
                    //modelTeamSelect.team.TeamName = string.Empty;
                    break;
            }
            return View(modelTeamSelect);
        }

        #region PartialView
        public PartialViewResult _PartialTeams(modelTeamSelect modelTeamSelect)
        {
            return PartialView("_PartialTeams", modelTeamSelect);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public PartialViewResult _PartialTeams(string BtnSubmit, modelTeamSelect modelTeamSelect)
        {
            FootballRepository = new Repository.FootballRepository();
            switch (BtnSubmit)
            {
                case "Add Team":
                    FootballRepository.AddTeam(modelTeamSelect.team);
                    modelTeamSelect.teams.Add(modelTeamSelect.team);
                    break;
                case "Asc":
                    modelTeamSelect.teams = FootballRepository.Sort(modelTeamSelect, BtnSubmit);
                    ModelState.Clear();
                    break;
                case "Desc":
                    modelTeamSelect.teams = FootballRepository.Sort(modelTeamSelect, BtnSubmit);
                    ModelState.Clear();
                    break;
            }
            return PartialView("~/Views/Partials/_PartialTeams.cshtml", modelTeamSelect);
        }


        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult _PartialTeams(modelTeamSelect modelTeamSelect)
        {

            return PartialView("~/Views/Partials/_PartialTeams.cshtml", modelTeamSelect);
        }



        #endregion

        public ActionResult MatchSelect()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your app description page.";

            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

When I click the link I get this error:

[image]

If I change it from an ajax link to a standard html link I get the runtime error screen, assuming because it's synchronous

[image]

This is my file structure:

[image]

I want it to be an Ajax link that calls the right method so I can asynchronously update that row.

Comment: Can you give me your model structure (modelTeamSelect)?

Comment: @PragneshKhalas Yes, I will update my post.

Comment: Where is your controller code?

Answer (score 0):

From the server error image you can see where MVC is looking to resolve your ActionLink reference for the partial file:

"~/Views/Shared/_PartialTeams.chshtml" or "~/Views/Home/_PartialTeams.chshtml"

In the screenshot of your folder structure the _PartialTeams.chshtml file is under the Partials folder.

Either move the file under the /Views/Home/ folder or the /Views/Shared/ and your solution will work.

**AS PER COMMENT**

In your controller _PartialTeams action use

```
return PartialView("~/Views/Partials/_PartialTeams.cshtml", modelTeamSelect);
```

but there's a caveat as soon as you start to move away from conventions it's harder for other people to start using your code and it will decrease maintainability over time

Comment: Is there no way to resolve the URL so it points to Partials? I want to keep my file structure organized.

Comment: @nickgowdy in your controller action result method use return "~/Views/Partials/_PartialTeams.cshtml" but there's a caveat as soon as you start to move away from conventions it's harder for other people to start using your code and it will decrease maintainability over time

Comment: I moved that partialview to the shared folder and I have realised I haven't described my problem very well. I want to update the teams using the actionlink. So the view and partial view should load again with the new value.